# Cost of building a "connected matrix"

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I'm sure there is an abundance of information on how to do exactly what I'm after, but it's a matter of not knowing the technical term for it. Basically what I want to create is an adjacency matrix for a directed graph, however rather than simply storing whether or not each vertex pair has a *direct* adjacency, for every vertex pair in the matrix I want to store if there is ANY path connecting the two (and what those paths are).

This would give me constant time complexity for lookups which is desirable, however what's not immediately clear to me is what the expected optimal time complexity of *building* this matrix will be.

Also, is there a formal name for such a matrix?

Playing this out in my head, it seems like a dynamic programming problem. If I want to know if A is connected to Z, I should be able to ask each of A's neighbors, B, C and D if they are (in some way) connected to Z, and if so, then I know A is. And if B doesn't have this answer stored, then he would ask the same question of *his* direct neighbors, and so on. I would memoize the results along the way, so subsequent lookups would be constant.

I haven't spent time to implement this yet, because it feels like ϴ(n^n) to build a complete matrix, so my question is whether or not I'm going about this the right way, and if indeed there is a lower-cost way to build such a matrix?

Comment: Calculating it is definetly cheaper than `O(n^n)`. You can just do BFS/DFS from each node, and get `O(|E|*|V|)` solution.

Comment: Thanks @amit. I meant to say n^2, but that's still not right. (I was thinking in terms of n being |V|). So I'll O(E*V) is as good as it gets.

Comment: To be precise, I was thinking it was O(n*(n+1)/2), considering a simple connected graph of a straight line where each vertex has at most one neighbor.

Comment: @amit is there a formal name for this type of matrix? I'm having some issues with the implementation, particularly where circuits exist, and I'd love to read anything about it I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transitive closure of a graph (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure#In_graph_theory) can indeed be computed by dynamic programming with a variation of Floyd Warshall algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm.

Using |V| DFS (or BFS) is more efficient, though.

Comment: DFS/BFS is more efficient, but in my case I have to do hundreds of thousands of searches to see if V1 is connected to V2, and so having the transitive closure will allow these checks to be O(1).

Comment: You can compute the matrix of the transitive closure with |V| DFS, and have O(1) query after. This is O((|E| + |V|) |V|) instead of O(|V|^3) with Floyd Warshall (better if |E| = o(|V|^2)), to achieve exactly the same goal.

Answer (score 0):

Using networkx [connected components](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components)

```
G = nx.path_graph(4)
G.add_path([10, 11, 12])
d = {}
for group in idx, group in enumerate(nx.connected_components(G)):
    for node in group:
        d[node] = idx

def connected(node1, node2):
    return d[node1]==d[node2]
```

Generation should be `O(N)` lookup should be `O(1)`